# Is it possible to use the dotnet tracing libraries on macOS?

Tags: .net-traceprocessing

I've gone through the example event-tracing projects located at https://github.com/microsoft/eventtracing-processing-samples and successfully built the projects. I'm running into missing dll's. For instance when running the `CountProcesses` example, I run into the following stack trace:

```
mono CountProcesses.exe test.etl

Unhandled Exception:
System.DllNotFoundException: msi.dll assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing.NativeMethods.MsiGetSummaryInformationW(uint,string,uint,uint&)
  at Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing.ToolkitTraceProcessingEngine.GetRevisionNumber (System.String msiPath) [0x00000] in <bdfe3783769b4c6f90b3788d264e0262>:0 
  at Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing.ToolkitTraceProcessingEngine.GetOrCreateDefaultToolkitPath (System.IO.TextWriter output) [0x00054] in <bdfe3783769b4c6f90b3788d264e0262>:0 
  at Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing.ToolkitTraceProcessingEngine.Create (System.String path, Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing.ITraceProcessorSettings settings, Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing.ITraceProcessorSettings& effectiveSettings) [0x000a8] in <bdfe3783769b4c6f90b3788d264e0262>:0 
  at Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing.TraceProcessor.Create (System.String path, Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing.ITraceProcessorSettings settings) [0x00000] in <bdfe3783769b4c6f90b3788d264e0262>:0 
  at Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing.TraceProcessor.Create (System.String path) [0x00000] in <bdfe3783769b4c6f90b3788d264e0262>:0 
  at Program.Run (System.String tracePath) [0x00001] in <2e2989aba7be4139841be131a5e978bb>:0 
  at Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00027] in <2e2989aba7be4139841be131a5e978bb>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: msi.dll assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing.NativeMethods.MsiGetSummaryInformationW(uint,string,uint,uint&)
  at Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing.ToolkitTraceProcessingEngine.GetRevisionNumber (System.String msiPath) [0x00000] in <bdfe3783769b4c6f90b3788d264e0262>:0 
  at Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing.ToolkitTraceProcessingEngine.GetOrCreateDefaultToolkitPath (System.IO.TextWriter output) [0x00054] in <bdfe3783769b4c6f90b3788d264e0262>:0 
  at Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing.ToolkitTraceProcessingEngine.Create (System.String path, Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing.ITraceProcessorSettings settings, Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing.ITraceProcessorSettings& effectiveSettings) [0x000a8] in <bdfe3783769b4c6f90b3788d264e0262>:0 
  at Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing.TraceProcessor.Create (System.String path, Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing.ITraceProcessorSettings settings) [0x00000] in <bdfe3783769b4c6f90b3788d264e0262>:0 
  at Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing.TraceProcessor.Create (System.String path) [0x00000] in <bdfe3783769b4c6f90b3788d264e0262>:0 
  at Program.Run (System.String tracePath) [0x00001] in <2e2989aba7be4139841be131a5e978bb>:0 
  at Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00027] in <2e2989aba7be4139841be131a5e978bb>:0
```

Before digging too deeply into the missing libraries, is traceprocessing intended to be cross-platform? Or does it rely on platform dependent libs in Windows?

System Setup:

- OS: macOS Catalina 10.15.4
- Mono JIT compiler version 6.8.0.105 (2019-10/82fffe07497 Tue Feb  4 10:09:51 EST 2020)
- .NET Core SDK (3.1.201)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I am a developer at Microsoft who works on the TraceProcessor project.)

Currently, the library relies on some Windows-only components and cannot be run on a Mac.

Comment: Are there any macos/linux alternatives for processing ETW (specifically .etl files) that you know of?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are none that I know of. The library that contains the [OpenTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/evntrace/nf-evntrace-opentracew) and [ProcessTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/evntrace/nf-evntrace-processtrace) methods needed to crack open an ETL file are Windows-specific.